# VBA - USERFORM - find value and fill row without activete or select

Tags: vba, excel

Is possible to do something like this without select sheet, or activate ? I need change values in cells with userform based on find key value.

```
Dim sonsat As Long
Sheets("DATA").Range("A:A").Find(Keycombobox.Text)
sonsat = ActiveCell.Row
Cells(sonsat, 1) = TextBox1
Cells(sonsat, 2) = TextBox2
Cells(sonsat, 3) = TextBox3
Cells(sonsat, 4) = TextBox4
Cells(sonsat, 5) = TextBox5
Cells(sonsat, 6) = TextBox6
Cells(sonsat, 7) = TextBox7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Find` method below (W/O using `Select`, `ActiveCell` and `Activate`).

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestFind()

Dim sonsat As Long
Dim FindRng As Range

With Sheets("DATA")
    Set FindRng = .Range("A:A").Find(Keycombobox.Text) ' <-- assuming  Keycombobox is a textBox

    If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then ' <-- successful find
        sonsat = FindRng.Row

        ' rest of yout code here ....
        .Cells(sonsat, 1) = TextBox1 '<-- for good coding practice use TextBox1.Value ' or TextBox1.Text
        .Cells(sonsat, 2) = TextBox2
        .Cells(sonsat, 3) = TextBox3
        .Cells(sonsat, 4) = TextBox4
        .Cells(sonsat, 5) = TextBox5
        .Cells(sonsat, 6) = TextBox6
        .Cells(sonsat, 7) = TextBox7
    Else
        MsgBox "Unable to find " & Keycombobox.Text & " in specified Range !"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This code give me new entry to sheet what I have selected, but not to place where was targeted cell values before edit. Userform is opened from different sheet.

Comment: I have one more question. Is it possible to integrate find.next funciton to this code? If Keycombobox.Text has same value in target range ? I need write  .Cells(sonsat, 1) = TextBox1(first find) TextBox11 (next find) and so on.

Comment: @Nataniell  I'm OOO, I'll look in to it tomorrow

Comment: ok, thx. I am not able to solve this. I have prepared multi page on my userform and every multipage has textbox for alternative find. Max number of same value is 20 so 20 pages.

Comment: @Nataniell I'm not sure I understand. Can you open a new post with your request ? Especialy load a screen-shot of your User_Form, how it look like, and what results you want to get (which objects inside the User_Form) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42084501/vba-userform-find-equall-value-and-make-entry-to-textbox-for-every-match

Answer (score 0):

you could go like follows

```
Dim i As Long

With Sheets("DATA").Range("A:A").Find(Keycombobox.Text)
    For i = 1 To 7
        Cells(.Row, i) = Me.Controls("TextBox" & i)
    Next
End With
```