# VBA - USERFORM - Find equall value and make entry for adjacent value in row to textbox for every match

Tags: vba, excel

I need upgrade this code to find.next version. In attachment is sample form for better understanding. Keycombobox value can be found more then once and every match for adjacent values has to be in adjacent textbox.

DATA SEMPLE Keytextbox value = TEST1

```
.Cells(row with FIRST find TEST1, 1) = textbox10 (located in multipage.page(find))
.Cells(row with SECOND find TEST1, 1) = textbox110 (locateted in multipage.page(alternative find))
```

[image]

```
Option Explicit

    Sub TestFind()

    Dim sonsat As Long
    Dim FindRng As Range

    With Sheets("DATA")
        Set FindRng = .Range("A:A").Find(Keycombobox.Text) ' <-- assuming  Keycombobox is a textBox

        If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then ' <-- successful find
            sonsat = FindRng.Row

            ' rest of yout code here ....
            .Cells(sonsat, 1) = TextBox10 '<-- for good coding practice use TextBox1.Value ' or TextBox1.Text
            .Cells(sonsat, 2) = TextBox20
            .Cells(sonsat, 3) = TextBox30
            .Cells(sonsat, 4) = TextBox40
            .Cells(sonsat, 5) = TextBox50
            .Cells(sonsat, 6) = TextBox60
            .Cells(sonsat, 7) = TextBox70
        Else
            MsgBox "Unable to find " & Keycombobox.Text & " in specified Range !"
        End If
    End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: What happnes if let's say a value of "Test1" in `Keycombobox` is found multiple times, where should the result be ? which `TextBox` ? what should be the returned results ?

Comment: If Keycombox is "Test1" and is founded twice. Then TextBox10 = .cells(row with "TEST1- first find", 2) and TextBox20= .cells(row with "TEST1- second find", 2)

Comment: Sorry `TextBox20` should be `TextBox110` from multipage alternative find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you're after this:

```
Sub TestFind()
    Dim f As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim iPage As Long, i As Long

    With Sheets("DATA").Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        Set f = .Find(what:=Keycombobox.Text, LookIn:=xlvalkue, lookat:=xlWhole) ' <-- assuming  Keycombobox is a textBox
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = f.address
            Do
                For i = 1 To 7
                    Me.Controls("TextBox" & iPage + i * 10) = .Cells(f.Row, i)
                Next
                iPage = iPage + 100
                Set f = .FindNext(f)
            Loop While f.address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Nataniell, did you get through it?

Comment: Yes its pretty close what I needed.I thought about it and will be better for me if I have only 7 text boxes and switch content in them. So I need upgrade your code to version where page bookmark from multipage only switch content in textboxes based on which bookmark is selected? `Page1 = first find->textbox1, Page2 = second find->textbox 1`

Comment: it's not clear to me your _new_ issue: you may want to elaborate on it with a more detailed example.  In the meanwhile if my answer solved your _original_ question you may want to mark it as accepted. Thank you